# C++ class variables as method parameters?

Tags: c++

When we are defining the method of a class, is it alright if we use the class variables (whether public or private) as  the method's-parameters?

In other words which one would be "more correct?"

Having defined ,

```
class myclass{
public:
    int x, y;
    double foo(int, int, int);
private: 
    int z;

}
```

is this ok

```
double myclass::foo(int x, int y, int z) {/* Blah Blah */}
```

or

```
double myclass::foo(int xx, int yy, int zz){x=xx; y=yy; z=zz  /*  Blah Blah*/}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two:

```
double myclass::foo(int x, int y, int z) {/* Blah Blah */}

double myclass::foo(int xx, int yy, int zz){x=xx; y=yy; z=zz  /*  Blah Blah*/}
```

Do not do the same thing. The first one declares a function who's arguments are called `x`, `y`, and `z`. Because they are named the same as class-scoped variables, they hide the class-scoped variables. To access the hidden members inside "Blah Blah", you would have to use `this->x` and so forth.

This *does not* cause the arguments to be forwarded directly into the values of the members of the class.

Comment: In the second one, after the method completes its execution, the class-member x will still retain the value set by xx, right?

Answer (score 3):

Either way is fine. If you need to disambiguate, just use the `this` keyword:

```
this->x = x;
```

Comment: Either way is **legal**.  But hiding variables is universally considered to be a bad idea.

Comment: Universally? Really? The language designers didn't think so.

Comment: @Chris: There are plenty of parts of C and C++ that are legal but not considered good form. Just because the language allows something doesn't mean that you should take advantage of it.

Comment: I'm just saying "universally" is a rather all-encompassing term. Surely there is some trivial case where making use of this feature is the lesser of two evils.

Answer (score 2):

It is "OK" in the same way that you are allowed open new scopes and hide names:

```
int a;

void foo()
{
  int a;
  {
    int a;
    // how do we refer to the other two now?
  }
}
```

If your function *definition* uses the same symbols for the argument variables as are already used in the class scope, then the functions-scope symbol hides the one in the outer scope. You can sometimes disambiguate (e.g. with `::a` in my example, or `this->x` in yours), but as my example shows, you can always hide a variable so much that it's no longer addressable.

In short, don't make your life hard, and stick to a sensible naming scheme that avoids unnecessary ambiguity. Programming is hard enough without tying your hands to your ankles.